# bundle command not found after upgrading to Ruby 2.0.0 on OSX

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundle

I can't run bundle. I just upgraded Ruby to 2.0.0 using rvm. I'm using rvm 1.23.4 on OSX Mountain Lion.

Any idea what to do?

```
echo $PATH
/Users/Mohamad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/Mohamad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/Users/Mohamad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/Mohamad/.rvm/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

**Update** I ran `gem list` and `bundler` does not appear to be installed.

```
capistrano (2.15.5)
highline (1.6.19)
i18n (0.6.5)
net-scp (1.1.2)
net-sftp (2.1.2)
net-ssh (2.7.0)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
rake (10.1.0)
sshkit (1.0.0)
term-ansicolor (1.2.2)
tins (0.12.0)
```

Comment: how about `gem list` and `gem list bundler -d`?

Comment: Duhhh... forget to install bundler after switching to Ruby 2.0.0. Thank you.

Comment: rvm should install it default for you ... unless you explicitly disabled this.

Comment: I have not. I'm using the latest rvm. When I ran `gem list`, bundler was not there. So I did `gem bundle install`.

Comment: Question.. what does the `-d` flag mean?

Comment: `-d` shows the details of the gems including installation path

Answer (score 1):

RVM should install this gem for you - if it was not done this is a bug - open a ticket here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues